# How to make relational mapping between entities using mongoDB in sprinboot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to create a springboot application using MongoDB and a Rest controller and connect objects together using DBRef instead of classic Jpa annotations like OneToMany etc. The purpose is to print all the bookmarks for a specific account. The list of bookmarks is found by the username but it seems that it doesn't work.

These are my classes:

```
@Document
public class Account {
    @DBRef
    private Set<Bookmark> bookmarkSet = new HashSet<>();

    @Id
    private String id;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public Account(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setBookmarkSet(Set<Bookmark> bookmarkSet) {
        this.bookmarkSet = bookmarkSet;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

@Document
public class Bookmark {

    @DBRef
    @JsonIgnore
    private Account account;

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String uri;
    private String description;

    public Bookmark(Account account, String uri, String description) {
        this.account = account;
        this.uri = uri;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

repositories:

```
public interface AccountRepository extends MongoRepository<Account, Long> {
    Optional<Account> findOneByUsername(String username);
}

public interface BookmarkRepository extends MongoRepository<Bookmark, Long> {
    Collection<Bookmark> findByAccountUsername(String username);
}
```

And RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/{userId}/bookmarks")
public class BookmarkRestController {
    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;
    private final BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository;

    @Autowired
    public BookmarkRestController(AccountRepository accountRepository, BookmarkRepository bookmarkRepository) {
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
        this.bookmarkRepository = bookmarkRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{bookmarkId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    Bookmark readBookmark(@PathVariable String userId, @PathVariable Long bookmarkId) {
        this.validateUser(userId);
        return bookmarkRepository.findOne(bookmarkId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    Collection<Bookmark> readBookmarks(@PathVariable String userId) {
        this.validateUser(userId);
        return this.bookmarkRepository.findByAccountUsername(userId);
    }

    private void validateUser(String userId) {
        this.accountRepository.findOneByUsername(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(userId));
    }
}
```

After I run the application I get this error:

```
Invalid path reference account.username! Associations can only be pointed to directly or via their id property!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you have the right schema design.  I assume you've modeled you objects based on a relational database type model, where the data is normalised and data is split across multiple tables, with relationships captured using Ids.  With MongoDB you can structure and store your data with the heirarchy simply contained in within the one document.

So in your example the Bookmark would not be a Document itself, but would be a sub document of the Account.  Remove the `@Document` annotation from the Bookmark object, and the `@DBRef` annotations, and simply store the Bookmarks within the Account document.

This would give you a schema more like this:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "bookmarkSet": [
    {
      "uri": "http://www.foo.com",
      "description": "foo"
    },
    {
      "uri": "http://www.bar.com",
      "description": "bar"
    }
  ],
  "username": "John",
  "password": "password"
}
```

*Note: if you make the bookmarks sub documents you can remove the _id member from the Bookmark object

The best design will depend on how many bookmarks you expect each account to have.  If its only a few bookmarks then what I suggested would work well.  If you have thousands then you might want to structure it differently.  There are lots of articles about schema design in NoSQL database.  This one covers the options for embedding subdocuments quite well:
http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Comment: But how to store them if I have 1000 bookmarks, It would be crazy to store them manually. I should use Autowire ? or how exactly ?